# ddeboer/data-import null values for CSV

Tags: symfony, csv, import

What is the proper format for a null value when importing CSV file using `ddeboer/data-import` bundle in Symfony2?

The `CSVReader` class uses `SplFileObject` class and it escapes anything. If I use `\N` for instance it changes it to `\\N`.

I've tried empty value formats, like `..,,..` or `...,"",...` and it always says that the value is not correct for an integer field.

The MySQL field is nullable or allow null, I must be able to use null values and not 0 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for this problem and it's using a CallbackItemConverter.

So each item is checked if it's a string and its value is "NULL" change it to a PHP null value.

```
$nullConverter = new CallbackItemConverter(function ($item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $item[$key] = $value == 'NULL'? null: $value;
        }
    }
    return $item;
});

$workflow->addItemConverter($nullConverter)
```

Actually you can change the string "NULL" to any value you use in your CSV export, and use the same converter to convert any other fields while the workflow is processing.